# orientation of normal surface/vertex vectors

Tags: numpy, vector-graphics, normals

Given a convex 3d polygon (convex hull) How can I determine the correct direction for normal surface/vertex vectors? As the polygon is convex, by correct I mean outward facing (away from the centroid).

```
def surface_normal(centroid, p1, p2, p3):
    a = p2-p1
    b = p3-p1
    n = np.cross(a,b)
    if **test including centroid?** :
        return n
    else:
        return -n # change direction
```

I actually need the normal vertex vectors as I am exporting as a .obj file, but I am assuming that I would need to calculate the surface vectors before hand and combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should work under the assumption of a convex hull in 3d. You calculate the normal as shown in the question. You can normalize the normal vector with

```
n /= np.linalg.norm(n)  # which should be sqrt(n[0]**2 + n[1]**2 + n[2]**2)
```

You can then calculate the center point of your input triangle:

```
pmid = (p1 + p2 + p3) / 3
```

After that you calculate the distance of the triangle-center to your surface centroid. This is

```
dist_centroid = np.linalg.norm(pmid - centroid)
```

The you can calculate the distance of your triangle_center + your normal with the length of the distance to the centroid.

```
dist_with_normal = np.linalg.norm(pmid + n * dist_centroid - centroid)
```

If this distance is larger than dist_centroid, then your normal is facing outwards. If it is smaller, it is pointing inwards. If you have a perfect sphere and point towards the centroid, it should almost be zero. This may not be the case for your general surface, but the convexity of the surface should make sure, that this is enough to check for its direction.

```
if(dist_centroid < dist_with_normal):
    n *= -1
```

---

Another, nicer option is to use a scalar product.

```
pmid = (p1 + p2 + p3) / 3
if(np.dot(pmid - centroid, n) < 0):
    n *= -1
```

This checks if your normal and the vector from the mid of your triangle to the centroid have the same direction. If that is not so, change the direction.